# focus issue when I click copy button using document.execCommand('copy')

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, copy, focus

I have a copy button created by javascript, and its has onclick event like this:

```
let copyButton = document.createElement("button");

copyButton.onclick = {

   const textLabel = document.createElement('textarea');
   textLabel.value = copyText;
   document.body.appendChild(textLabel);
   textLabel.select();
   document.execCommand('copy');
   document.body.removeChild(textLabel);
};
```

It is lose focus when I click this button because the `textLabel.select()` function call.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Thanks so much.

Comment: There are much better modern alternatives to copying content now [MDN Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard)

Comment: The code posted does not work as it is. The button is never added to the DOM and copyText is not defined. Please update this to reflect the actual code